# Получение тела POST-запроса из http.ClientRequest в node.js

Tags: node.js

Нужно получить POST параметры, без каких то библиотек, на чистом node.js .И можно ли так?

Comment: Откуда получить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прочитайте раздел `http` в документации к [node.js](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/http.html)

В самом примерном виде это реализуется так:

```js
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (req.method == 'POST') {
    var body = '';
    req.on('data', function(data) {
      body += data;
      console.log("Partial body: " + body);
    });
    req.on('end', function() {
      console.log("Body: " + body);
    });
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });
    res.end('post received');
  }
  ...
});
```

Comment: Спасибо =)   Очень помог